# Unity trouble syncing audio and visuals for rhythm game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I am trying to make a rhythm game in Unity, but I am having trouble syncing the audio and visual elements of the game. The objects you are supposed to click on the beat are synced with the music perfectly at the beginning of the song, but by the end of the song, they are behind the song by about a half beat. I am using AudioSettings.dspTime to schedule the spawning of all of my objects, which is what is recommended, so I have no idea what is going wrong. Here is the code I use to spawn objects:

```
//void Update() {
//...
if (playing && !finished)
{
    string[] nextNote = notes[currentNote];

    float noteBeat = float.Parse(nextNote[0]);
    int notePos = int.Parse(nextNote[1]);

    float currentTime = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime - startTime - offset + approachTime;
    float currentBeats = currentTime / (60 / bpm);

    while (currentBeats - (noteBeat - 1) >= 0 && !finished)
    {
        if (nextNote.Length == 2)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(noteObject, noteField.transform);

            go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(notePos) * 30 + (notePos - Mathf.Sign(notePos)) * 62.5f, 0);
            go.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
            go.GetComponent<Note>().SetLane(notePos);
        }

        else
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(lyricObject, lyricField.transform.GetChild(notePos - 1));

            go.GetComponent<Lyric>().SetLyric(nextNote[2], notePos);
        }

        if (currentNote < notes.Length - 1)
        {
            nextNote = notes[++currentNote];

            noteBeat = float.Parse(nextNote[0]);
            notePos = int.Parse(nextNote[1]);
        }

        else
        {
            finished = true;
            playing = false;

            Invoke("EndSong", startDelay + approachTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I should clarify anything in my code or add more. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed my own problem. Turns out the song I was using was not playing at a constant BPM.